# Many to Many relationship calling on Flask SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, relationship

I have the following badge (achievement) system database structure:

```
class Base(db.Model):

__abstract__ = True

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp())
date_modified = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp(),
                          onupdate=db.func.current_timestamp())

class User(UserMixin, Base):

__tablename__ = 'users'

username = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
email = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
password = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
badges = db.relationship('UserBadge', backref='ubadge',
                            lazy='dynamic')

class Badge(Base):

__tablename__ = 'badges'

name = db.Column(db.String(35), unique=True)
description = db.Column(db.String(300))
imgfile = db.Column(db.String(80))
badges = db.relationship('UserBadge', backref='badge',
                            lazy='dynamic')

def __repr__(self):
    return '<Achievement: {} - {}>'.format(self.name, self.description)

class UserBadge(Base):

__tablename__ = 'userbadges'

user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
badge_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('badges.id'))

def __repr__(self):
    return '<Achievement: {} - {}>'.format(self.user_id, self.badge_id)
```

So i can return all the badges by a specific user, using:

```
ubadges = UserBadge.query.filter_by(user_id=user.id).all()
```

It returns:

```
 [<Achievement: 1 - 1>]
```

But instead of 1 (user_id) and 1 (badge_id) i want to show the users.name and badges.name. How can i access those attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `UserBadge` class, just use:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '<Achievement: {} - {}>'.format(self.ubadge.name, self.badge.name)
```

It has both properties because you set them up using `backref` in the other classes.

PS: You might need to change the `User` `backref` to `user`, and then use `self.user.name` int he function above